# VBA Case Insensitive Advanced Filter Sort

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a macro to remove duplicates from a list of data - I now need to modify this code so that it is case insensitive (e.g. so duplicate records that are spelt the same are removed, regardless of capitalisation).

For example, if I had a list of the following:

```
BALL
Ball
Cat 
CAT
Dog
```

I would like the macro to output:

```
Ball
Cat 
Dog
```

Here is the code I have at the moment - any help will be appreciated (please note that I have tried inserting the "Option Compare Text" command at the start of the module):

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Delete_Duplicates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Proposal Database").Activate

With ActiveSheet

.Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("A2"), Unique:=True

End With

Worksheets("Input Screen").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the excel-built-in function (which is case insensitive) like this:

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Proposal Database").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Columns(2).RemoveDuplicates

    Worksheets("Input Screen").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but, unfortunately the code is nto working. The cod eexecutes correctly but does not remove the duplciates from column (2) do you know why this might be the case? Thanks.

Comment: Now solved the problem - I needed to add on Column and XlHeader parameters after the line ending ActiveSheet.Columns(2).RemoveDuplicates - thanks for your help!

Comment: Ohh... forgot about that ^^